# C++ , A2oj.com , Supermarket

Tags: c++

This is Problem

357. Supermarket

Problem Statement:
You're in a supermarket and want to buy N items but you have only S dollars.

Input Format:
first two numbers N (the number of items) and S (The amount of dollars you have) followed by N integers indicate the price of each item 
N is a positive integers less than or equal to 1,000,000 
0 < S < 1,000,000,001 
All prices are less than 1,000,001

Output Format:
Print "Yes" if the total price of items less than or equal to S and print "No" otherwise.

Sample Input:
6 100 8 31 4 12 19 2

Sample Output:
Yes

Notes:
8 + 31 + 4 + 12 + 19 + 2 = 76

76 < 100

Then "Yes" you can buy them

This is My Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    int N,S;
    cin >> N >> S;
    int sum=0;
    int numslist[N];
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        cin>>numslist[i];
        sum=sum+numslist[i];
    }
    if(sum<=S)
        cout << "No" << endl;
    else if(sum>S)
        cout << "Yes" << endl;
    return 0;
    }
```

I submit This Code and The Online Judge and it say Wrong answer [Website](http://www.a2oj.com/p.jsp?ID=357)

Please any one Help me and say What's the wrong?

Comment: Excuse me , I new to c++ ,what do you mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not declare an array with a size that is only known at run-time, it must be known at compile time (ignoring compiler extensions). So you cannot do this

```
int N;
cin >> N;
int numslist[N];
```

Instead you could do

```
int N;
cin >> N;
vector<int> numslist(N);
```